# Excel VBA: Can an array of dates be transposed?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, transpose

I have two arrays that I need to paste into my spreadsheet. Since each destination is a column, I'm using the Transpose command, like so:

```
Selection = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr1)
```

This works for one of the arrays, but the other gives me an Invalid Procedure Call (Error 5). Both arrays are the same size: arr(1 to 79).

The only difference between the two that I can tell is that all the values in the "good" array are Variant/String, and most of the ones in the "bad" array are Variant/Date.

Should that actually make a difference? If so, is there a way of converting the values in the latter array?

Comment: Both `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` and `Application.Transpose` methods work successfully when I test this. Can you show more of your code and possibly example data?

Comment: @DavidZemens are you transposing a 1D array?

Comment: @Mat'sMug yes, e.g., `Dim arr1(2) As Variant` and then filled with `Date` type values.

Comment: Huh, I always assumed the function wanted to work with a 2D array

Comment: Transpose will turn a 1d array (*n* rows) in to a 2d array (1 column, *n* rows) @Mat'sMug

Comment: @DavidZemens I don't think that's true. I've been transposing 1D arrays all week, and they come out as 1D.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson no they don't.  http://imgur.com/a/ZgjIo

Answer (score 0):

Properly coded the following should work:

```
Sub DepositArrays()
    Dim ary1(1 To 2) As String, ary2(1 To 2) As Date

    ary1(1) = "James"
    ary1(2) = "Ravenswood"
    ary2(1) = DateSerial(1945, 1, 20)
    ary2(2) = Date

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Range("A1:A2") = .Transpose(ary1)
        Range("B1:B2") = .Transpose(ary2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Yields:

[image]

Without the `TRANSPOSE()`, the code runs, but will not produce correct results.

Answer (score 0):

why not to use a `range`:

```
Private Sub Test()

Dim arr(79) As Variant
For i = o To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = Now
Next

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(81, 2))
rng = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

End Sub
```

also another option is a simple loop to iterate trough the array and populate data to the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Test2()

Dim arr(79) As Variant
For i = o To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = Now
Next

For i = o To UBound(arr)
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = arr(i)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I *am* using a range. (Actually, a column of a ListObject). For simplicity, I tested it with Selection, and got the same error, so that's what I posted.

Comment: Using a loop will slow my procedure to a crawl. Arrays are much faster. (When they work!)

Comment: i have assumed the reason was efficiency...but if there are not many indexes inside the array it possible to set `application.ScreenUpdating` property to False and set `Application.Calculation` to xlCalculateManual. it will speed up the execution dramatically (in case you are not familiar with it)

Answer (score 0):

Both methods work for me, whether I use `Transpose` as a member of the `Application` class or the `WorksheetFunction` class. If any element of the array contains a string >= 255 characters in length, I get a **Type Mismatch** error, but I can't replicate the **Invalid Procedure Call** error.

Can you test this in a blank workbook?

```
Sub foo()
Dim arr1(79), vals, rng As Range
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    arr1(i) = DateAdd("d", i, #1/1/2016#)
Next

Set rng = Range("A1:A80")
rng = Application.Transpose(arr1)
vals = arr1

Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
rng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr1)

'Both methods work even if the destination range is the wrong size:
Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(100)
rng = Application.Transpose(arr1)

Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(50)
rng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr1)


End Sub
```